# https on port 3000, how to set up express.js and sites-available.conf on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: express, ssl, ubuntu-22.04

I would like this to work :
https://amaurypichat.fr:3000/getdata

The certificate is not working (because it s not connected to port 443)
I made this with express.js :

```
var privateKey  = fs.readFileSync('/etc/ssl/private/apache-selfsigned.key', 'utf8');
var certificate = fs.readFileSync('/etc/ssl/certs/apache-selfsigned.crt', 'utf8');

var credentials = {key: privateKey, cert: certificate};
var httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials, app);
httpsServer.listen(3000,function (err) {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        console.log("Server listening on PORT");
    });
```

and this is sites-available.conf :

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
   DocumentRoot /var/www/html/prod

   SSLEngine on
   SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/apache-selfsigned.crt
   SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/apache-selfsigned.key
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
       ServerName amaurypichat.fr
       Redirect / https://amaurypichat.fr/
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =amaurypichat.fr
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

What to do ? You can follow the link I gave to see actual pages.

Comment: you probabably don't need to run https web server on port 3000, better make a proxy location in your web server which connect to your api, so ```client->https://front_server/api ->http://api:3000```instead of redirecting to API service

the problem in CN of certificate, because port is a part of origin,  it tricky (and I not sure possible in general) to make certificate for url with port

can't help much with apache because I not remember it's syntax

Comment: additionally you will have a CORS problem when fetching /getdata from primary page

Comment: I don't understand what to do with the proxy, what will be the entry of it and its ouput ? There is not so much documentation of that in my case. I just dont understand

Comment: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/reverse_proxy.html  , in short it is better for you to create location /getdata in web server, which **instead of redirect** will pass connection from client to /getdata service, and for browser it will look like single emdpoint. Usually on bigger app such setup looks like nginx -> frontend and backend, where nginx just route connection.

Comment: For that, I just need to change the listening port of express or do I have to leave express ? How to do then ?

Comment: In express remove certificate records,  listen only on local interfaces, remember you go to express through apache which bother about ssl connection, google how to do this it is common architecture, notice headers like X-* to help you pass something like client ip